# Как прочитать метку MifareClassic с помощью класса NfcA?

Tags: java, android, nfc

Добрый день, у меня есть NFC метка с поддержкой технологий NfcA и MifareClassic.
Как прочитать содержимое метки используя класс NfcA?
Ключ для аутентификации технологии Mifare A0A1A2A3A4A5

```
public static String[] readTag(Tag tag) {
    byte[] readedData;
    byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[]{(byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0xA1, (byte) 0xA2, (byte) 0xA3, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0xA5};
    NfcA nfca = NfcA.get(tag);
    try {

        nfca.connect();
        readedData = nfca.transceive(new byte[]{
                (byte) 0x30,
                (byte) (0 & 0x0ff) // Чтение первой страницы без пароля, обычной метки не Mifare (для примера)
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

[image: Команды для transceive]

Comment: почему вы не хотите использовать класс MifareClassic? и какой сокральный смысл заключается в этом?

Comment: Нужно, для реализации дополнительных функций, спасибо.

Comment: @LexHobbit возможно это вам поможет https://goo.gl/18LHzT - здесь аутентификация NFCA (не Mifare), и ещё https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561858/how-send-nfca-command-to-the-mifare-card

Comment: Сначала отправьте вейкап и авторизацию, а потом уже х30

Answer (score 0):

Самое главное - надо проверить поддерживает ли ваше устройство чтение метки MIFARE Classic:

```
public static boolean hasMifareClassicSupport() {
    if (mHasMifareClassicSupport != 0) {
        return mHasMifareClassicSupport == 1;
    }

    // проверяем есть ли поддержка NFC на устройстве
    if (NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(mAppContext) == null) {
        mUseAsEditorOnly = true;
        mHasMifareClassicSupport = -1;
        return false;
    }

    // Чипы Broadcom не поддерживают MIFARE Classic.
    File device = new File("/dev/bcm2079x-i2c");
    if (device.exists()) {
        mHasMifareClassicSupport = -1;
        return false;
    }

    // Чипы NXP поддерживают MIFARE Classic.
    device = new File("/dev/pn544");
    if (device.exists()) {
        mHasMifareClassicSupport = 1;
        return true;
    }

    //проверяем наличие необходимых библиотек в системе
    File libsFolder = new File("/system/lib");
    File[] libs = libsFolder.listFiles();
    for (File lib : libs) {
        if (lib.isFile()
                && lib.getName().startsWith("libnfc")
                && lib.getName().contains("brcm")
                ) {
            mHasMifareClassicSupport = -1;
            return false;
        }
    }

    mHasMifareClassicSupport = 1;
    return true;
}
```

После этого можно пробовать читать.
Сначала выполните аутентификацию с использованием `authenticateSectorWithKeyA()` (если у вас есть ключ A, в противном случае используйте `authenticateSectorWithKeyB()` с ключом B). Если получаем `false`, аутентификация завершилась неудачно (ваш ключ был неправильным).

Когда аутентификация прошла успешно, вы можете использовать `readBlock()` для чтения данных (для удобства вы можете использовать `sectorToBlock()` для преобразования из индекса сектора в индекс блока)

Не переживайте о неудачной аутентификации: это не повлияет на работу вашей карты.

Релизацтю чтения по описанному выше алгоритму можно найти в приложении [MifareClassicTool](https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool).

Comment: Это не ответ на мой вопрос. Я знаю, как читать карту с помощью технологии MifareClassic. Вопрос: как прочитать данный тег с помощью технологии NfcA,если у меня есть ключ для технологии Mifare

Comment: @c0de вы плохо читаете, ссылку для чего вам дал?

Comment: Вы плохо читаете поставленный мною вопрос. Там нет реализации чтения тега с помощью технологии NfcA.

Comment: @c0de а метод readSector по-вашему [здесь](https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool/blob/master/Mifare%20Classic%20Tool/app/src/main/java/de/syss/MifareClassicTool/MCReader.java) что делает?

Comment: Читает метку с помощью класса (технологии) MifareClassic. Мне нужно чтобы читало с помощью класса NfcA

Comment: @c0de тогда посмотрите updateTagInfo в [этом классе](https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool/blob/a3eb1c62a88053dad6d238f7ee3ee09bfd8156e8/Mifare%20Classic%20Tool/app/src/main/java/de/syss/MifareClassicTool/Activities/TagInfoTool.java)

Comment: Здесь класс NFCA используется для получения UID. Не для чтения метки. MifareClassicTool вообще не читает метки с технологией NfcA, там даже в описании об этом написано.

Comment: @c0de дак а как вы хотите читать метку без аутентификации используя NfcA, если он не поддерживает ее?

Comment: Аутентификация должна быть проведена с помощью метода transceive и команд, и я спрашиваю, как это сделать, как составить команду для чтения, если у меня есть ключ A0A1A2A3A4A5, спасибо!

Comment: @c0de ааааааа теперь понял, щас поправлю ответ